# Trouble Awaiting Task in UI

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

The following method, running in the MainWindow code behind in my WPF app, is producing a well-documented StackOverflow error:

```
        async void LDAPLookupButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            input = LDAPInputFileLocationTextBox_Value.Text;

            LDAPProgress.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            await Task.Run(() => LDAPLookups.ExportToCSV(input));
            LDAPProgress.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
```

This results in error:

> The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.

Adjusting the method per the recommended guidance allows the app to run, but as expected the UI is blocked during execution of the Dispatcher action:

```
            async void LDAPLookupButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                input = LDAPInputFileLocationTextBox_Value.Text;

                LDAPProgress.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

                Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                     LDAPLookups.ExportToCSV(input);
                });

                LDAPProgress.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            }
```

I have two questions at this point:

1. Why is the "calling thread must be STA..." error being called when the *LDAPLookups.ExportToCSV* method is making no updates to the UI? The method runs out of another class and simply creates a .csv on the local machine.
2. How can I allow this to run while not blocking the UI?

Comment: The only reason why I can see this error occurring is if `ExportToCSV`(remember it is now running in a worker thread)  is accessing the UI.  Is it?  Using `Dispatcher.Invoke*` is kinda pointless for `async/await` particularly when you are already in a UI callback

Comment: Ah. I found a line where I had created an instance of MainWindow inside of the LDAPLookups class (static MainWindow main = new MainWindow();). I removed that and am no longer experiencing the error. Curious that simply creating an instance of the MainWindow, but not manipulating any of the properties or controls is enough to generate that error.

Comment: OK, I've posted my comment as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summay of comment beneath question above

---

The only reason why I can see this error occurring is if `ExportToCSV` (remember it is now running in a **worker thread** and a worker thread may not directly access the UI) is accessing the UI. Is it?

Also, using `Dispatcher.Invoke*` is kinda pointless for `async/await` particularly when you are already in a UI callback.

Be sure to check the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

for second question Use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() which would be called asynchronously.

Comment: That does make it asynchronous, but I need to await the finish of the method. If I add an await before the Dispatcher.BeginInvoke, I'm back to blocking the UI.

Comment: Whilst true, OP is using `async/await` and is already on the UI thread.  The problem is in the worker thread